# Multiple Select (MultiSelect) DropDownList with CheckBoxes in ASP.Net using jQuery on Modal popup through server side calling the popup

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-multiselect

How to work on Multiple Select (MultiSelect) DropDownList with CheckBoxes in ASP.Net using jQuery on Bootstrap Modal popup and call that popup through server side

```
    $(function () {
        $('[id*=ctl00_ContentSection_Internal]').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
    })

</script>
```

Comment: you can refer this http://jsfiddle.net/d6q9vbLe/5/

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
<input type="button" id="btnget" value="Show Popup" />

<div class="modal fade" id="mymodal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

          <select id="veggies" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
            <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
            <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
            <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
            <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
            <option value="onions">Onions</option>
          </select>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

$(function() {
  $('#veggies').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true
  });

  $('#btnget').click(function() {
    $('#mymodal').modal('show');
  })
});
```

Css Code-

```
.multiselect-container>li>a>label {
  padding: 4px 20px 3px 20px;
}
```